# Qlik Sense Drawing multi line graph

Tags: mongodb, linegraph, qliksense

I'm new to Qlik Sense. I've data from MongoDB and trying to visualize data using Qlik Sense.

Data:

```
Name    Time                 Value
Sig0    1434443400061   0.78535046693984389
Sig0    1434365571861   0.47410865876843988
Sig0    1434367800061   0.52816115795111507
Sig1    1434443400062   0.54981022370331589
Sig1    1434365571862   0.48053196850949664
Sig1    1434367800062   0.28258334531262386
```

How to draw Multi Line Graph?

```
X Axis - time
Y Axis - Line 1 - Sig0
Y Axis - Line 1 - Sig1
```

Currenty, im connecting to QV Source MongDBConenctor to load data.

Any suggestions would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple bit of splitting your data into Sig0 and Sig1 is done with an if statement in your measure expression.

```
sum(if(Name='Sig0',Value))
```

[image: Add a measure]

Same for Sig1. 
That will draw this graph. You'll have to do the time to normal date conversion yourself.
[image]

Comment: This should be done with set analysis. Not using the syntax above.. sum({<Name={'Sig0'}>} Value)

Answer (score 0):

The correct SET analysis syntax for this is sum({} Value) not the answer above.

Comment: I don't agree that this can or should only be done with SET analysis, SET will certainly also work. But it is definitely not the only way as evidenced by the if() method giving the correct answer

Comment: You will have performance issues if you do it the way you are suggesting on a big data set. Best practice is set analysis method.

Comment: from this link http://www.bardess.com/qlikview-application-performance-tuning/   'if more than 20% of the records in Sales table belong to Shoe, then the if function might have an advantage because it takes time for the Set Analysis expression to use indexes to figure out what records of the fact table contains Shoe data'.    I am also willing to take the minimal performance knock to have QlikView remain Qlik-y. With set analysis the user could not use selections to do analysis on a subset that the designer has not created before hand